# Include Pod's Bridging-Header to Build Settings of Project's Target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, bridging-header

I created an objective-c pod with two files:

```
Source/SomeViewController.h
Source/SomeViewController.m
```

I also created a bridging header in the pod:

```
Source/Bridging-Header.h
```

with the content:

```
#import "SomeViewController.h"
```

My podspec looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'TestLib'
  s.version = '0.0.1'
  s.license = 'MIT'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '7.0' 
  s.source_files = 'Source/*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER' => 'Source/Bridging-Header.h' } 
end
```

I created a demo project did `pod init` and inserted my pod. Then after `pod install` I get the following output:

Installing TestLib 0.0.1 (was 0.0.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

```
[!] The `TestLibProject [Debug]` target overrides the `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestLibProject/Pods-TestLibProject.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `TestLibProject [Release]` target overrides the `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestLibProject/Pods-TestLibProject.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

When I open my `TestLibProject.xcworkspace` file I see that the pod was installed correctly but the bridging header from the pod is not installed correctly. I my Swift project I tried to do:

```
let vc: SomeViewController
```

This gives an error because the bridging header from the pod ist not installed.

**How do I have to configure the `podspec` in order to get the bridging header of the pod being installed correctly?**

Answer (score 1):

Podspecs build frameworks, and frameworks cannot include bridging headers. If you want to import non-modular code into a Swift framework, you'll need to use a custom module map, instead, *e.g.* at **MyLib/module.modulemap**:

```c
framework module MyLib {
    umbrella header "MyLib.h"

    // Load an SDK header, e.g. CommonCrypto.h
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

Once there, you can specify the custom module map both in your Xcode project (either as the `MODULEMAP_FILE` setting in an **.xcconfig** file, or as the **Module Map File** of your target's **Build Settings**.

Now, the final piece of the puzzle: the podspec. You need to set the `module_map`:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  # …
  s.module_map = 'MyLib/module.modulemap'
end
```

The above is how [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) distributes itself, both as a general framework and as a pod.

---

*Edit:* Seems like I missed the point of the original question, as was clarified [in this thread](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/44#issuecomment-108137643). The OP wanted to use a pod framework's bridging header to automatically load itself into the installing project's Swift code. This isn't possible. Even if Swift frameworks *did* support bridging headers, they would only be able to load Objective-C/C code (*i.e.* private framework code) into the framework's Swift code.